# Для чего нужна function __

Tags: php, ооп, autoload

Добрый день, в программировании я новичок и сейчас прохожу стажировку и мне дали код для разбора,подскажите для чего он нужен, искал в интернете, но толком не разобрался

```
function __($key, $alt_value = ''){
    return Lang::get($key, $alt_value);
}
```

Эта функция находится в классе autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего используется для поиска перевода текста переданного в параметре `$alt_value` на язык указанный в параметре `$key`.
Зависит от того, на каком фреймворке/cms написан проект. Аналогичные функции есть в Kohana (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427204/php-what-does-some-text-do) и в Wordpress (http://wp-kama.ru/function/__).

Answer (score 1):

`__` Используется для локализации.

Встречается в основном в фреймворках Kohana и CakePHP. Система **I18n**

Подробно: [Тут](http://kohanaframework.su/guide/translation_files)